# The same function is called two times in two different activity

Tags: android

I am trying to make my first app in android studio and I have an issue, I have 2 activities and in both I have

```java
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Log.e(TAG, "onWindowFocusChanged()");
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }
    private void hideSystemUI() {
        Log.e(TAG, "hideSystemUI()");
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
```

But, when I change my activity to another one, the function is called from both activities, I don't want to destroy activity.

Should I make a third activity that contains this code and then remove from last two activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really, really common problem!

One solution is to create a `BaseActivity` that contains the shared code. Your two activities can then both extend `BaseActivity` to gain that functionality.

If you need more help with extending classes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47507674/608312) covers the same problem.